# Why is export {} causing Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. error?

Tags: typescript

When trying to make a class in typescript I encountered the issue where 'Project' can't be compiled as a module so I added the empty export `export {}`.

What I don't understand is why it now gives the error that it's an unexpected token. Am I missing something that I should've added?

```js
class Project {

    title: string;
    description: string;
    image: HTMLImageElement;

    constructor(
        title: string,
        description: string,
        image: HTMLImageElement
    ) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }
    export {};
}
```

Also not sure what additional info would be useful.

Comment: That `export` statement is in the middle of a class, which isn't a thing. Either move it outside of the class, or tell us what you're trying to do

Comment: Ah I see, tyvm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot `export` something from inside a `class` block.

> You can export functions, var, let, const, and — as we'll see later —
> classes. They need to be top-level items; you can't use export inside
> a function, for example. - [JavaScript modules (developer.mozilla.org)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)

What you need to do is move the `export` statement outside of the class and it will work just fine.

```
class Project {

    title: string;
    description: string;
    image: HTMLImageElement;

    constructor(
        title: string,
        description: string,
        image: HTMLImageElement
    ) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }
}

export {};
```

Comment: Very clear. Thanks!